# Unable to get AccessToken using OAuth2 to impliment Google Document List Api

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

In my ASP.NET application I am implementing Google Document List API, to fetch User data I using OAuth2 to do so I did some code:

```
string CLIENT_ID = "123456789321.apps.googleusercontent.com";
string CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string SCOPE = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
string REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";


        parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
        parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
        parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
        parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
        parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
        parameters.AccessCode = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessCode"]);

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
        settings = new RequestSettings("My Application", parameters);
```

Every time `OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);` gives error that is:

Can any one tell me where I am doing mistake?

Also, how to access RefreshToken??

Comment: Are you building a web application but trying to use a client-side OAuth flow?

Comment: Sorry! Jan, I do not have much idea in OAuth? can you please suggest me some sample of server-side authentication, if there any...

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) is a detailed description of the web server flow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the redirect URI for installed in a web application.

I'd recommend you to update your code to use the newer Drive API, which also includes a complete ASP.NET sample application and tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Comment: Hi Claudio, I have to mention here.. that I have already completed my code using Document List API can I go with that? if no? then.. I do not have any idea in MVC as you link suggested is using MVC, can you please provide me sample code how to implement Drive API in ASP.NET WebForms??

Comment: You can keep using the Documents List API but take into account that all new development is done on the Drive API. I don't have a complete WebForms sample but the code at https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials can be used in any .NET application